# Looping through a List of objects with the same base class and extracting a certain class?

Tags: c#, class, object, inheritance

For example, I have a base class `Entity`, then two sub classes that derive from this, `LightEntity` and `PlayerEntity`.

I then have a `List<Entity> Entities` that holds `LightEntity`s and `PlayerEntity`s.

I wish to get all the `LightEntity`s from `Entities`.

I tried:

```
List<LightEntity> lights = new List<LightEntity>();
foreach (Entity ent in Entities)
{
    if(ent is LightEntity)
    {
        lights.Add(ent);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't like this as the compiler still seems to think that it might try to add just an `Entity` to a list of `LightEntity`.

I tried to cast `ent` to `LightEntity` but the compiler says it has no methods of converting an `Entity` to a `LightEntity`.

Comment: I wanted to tell you the cause. In c#, downcasting not allowed implicitly. This means you have to go ahead with explicit casting, which tells the CLR that it is safe in my case to do such downcast.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to filter the entities by type:

```
List<LightEntity> lights = new List<LightEntity>();
lights.AddRange(entities.OfType<LightEntity>());
```

Or even easier:

```
List<LightEntity> lights = entities.OfType<LightEntity>().ToList();
```

**Further Reading**

- [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)

Comment: Agreed Linq makes this very pretty :)

Comment: Is it bad I've not heard of Linq before? I only work on C# in my spare time.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not Linq but IEnumerable extensions

Comment: Thanks, the link didn't work but I found it from Googling the title you posted. Looks very useful and I'll definitely be using it in the future.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern Sorry for that. I've added the link to the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

just cast the ent to (LightEntity)
so

```
Lights.Add((LightEntity)ent);
```

Comment: `InvalidCastException was unhandled - Unable to cast object of type PlayerEntity to type LightEntity`

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern - Put the line inside the if statement.

Comment: That's odd because you are checking to see if ent is LightEntity. Does PlayerEntity inherit from LightEntity or something?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Derp... I've tried that way but I wasn't checking the type first. And Kyle yeah, it works fine, I was being stupid!

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern no worries.

Comment: Thanks for helping but I'm going to go with p.s.w.g answer as it taught me something new and works much easier than what I was doing.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern Agreed, I like his solution better too.

Answer (score 2):

Well the List(Of T) extension solutions has already been written, so let me show this old fashioned way

```
List<LightEntity> lights = new List<LightEntity>();
foreach (Entity ent in Entities)
{
    LightEntity le = ent as LightEntity
    if(le != null)
    {
        lights.Add(le);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with linq...

```
 var lights = Entities.Where(e => e is LightEntity)
                      .Select(e => (LightEntity)e)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all. I don't know why you are doing this, but I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to solve your problem. Probably your derived classes shouldn't have the same base class or something similar. You should give us the bigger picture if you want help with that.

As has been posted already, casting is the solution to your problem.

```
Lights.Add((LightEntity)ent);
```

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to wonder if they really need the same base class, they do share a lot of common code though (base update functions, base draw functions, a lot of member variables), and storing them in the same list is because an Entity can have many child entities and I needed a way to keep them all in one place, in order to store the relationship and update them from Parent->Child